# How to make factory method to load fragments in activity android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to make a factory method in java class then call that method in activity to loading multiple fragments.

```
   @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.Men: {
            FirstFragment firstfragment = new FirstFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, firstfragment);
            transaction.commit();

            break;
            case R.id.Men: {
            SecondFragment secondfragment = new SecondFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, secondfragment);
            transaction.commit();

            break;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

static factory method, you can simply keep everything in fragment and no need to expose. Whoever needs to use this fragment will have a clear idea what it requires and also will not need to know what keys are. Just send the required params will be enough for them.

```
class FragmentFoo extends Fragment{
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
 private String name;


  public static Fragment newInstance(String name){
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putString(KEY_NAME, "name");
   Fragment fragment = new FragmentFoo();
   fragment.setArgs(bundle);

   return fragment;
   }
}
```

Comment: i want to only call static method and pass target fragment like-  loadFragment(new FirstFragment());